# Meteor autoform and Collection2 not saving data

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

I am having problems with Collection2 and autoform. Here is my collection

```js
Customers = new Mongo.Collection("customers");

Customers.allow({
 insert: function(userId, doc) {  
  return !!userId;
 }
});

CustomerSchema = new SimpleSchema({
 name: {
  type: String,
  label: "Name"
 },
 address: {
  type: String,
  label: "Address"
 },
 amount: {
  type: Number,
  label: "Amount"
 },
 bvn: {
  type: String,
  label: "BVN"
 },
 type: {
  type: String,
  label: "Sale Type"
 },
 saleDate: {
  type: Date,
  label: "Transaction Date",
  autoValue: function() {
   return new Date()
  },
  autoform: {
   type: "hidden"
  }
 },
 passport: {
  type: String,
  label: "Passport Number"
 },
 source: {
  type: String,
  label: "Source"
 },
 tickets: {
  type: Boolean,
  label: "Tickets"
 },
 visa: {
  type: Boolean,
  label: "Visa"
 },
 invoice: {
  type: Boolean,
  label: "Invoice"
 },
 nextSaleDate: {
  type: Date,
  label: "Next Sale Date",
  autoValue: function () {
   var thisDate = new Date();
   var dd = thisDate.getDate();
   var mm = thisDate.getMonth() + 3;
   var y = thisDate.getFullYear();

   var nextDate = dd + '/'+ mm + '/'+ y;
   return nextDate;
  },
  autoform: {
  type: "hidden"
  }
 },
 author: {
  type: String,
  label: "Author",
  autoValue: function () {
   return this.userId
  },
  autoform: {
  type: "hidden"
  }
 } 

});
Customers.attachSchema(CustomerSchema);
```

I have published and subscribed to the collections in separate publish and subscribe javascript files with methods `Meteor.publish('customers', function() {
    return Customers.find({author: this.userId});
});` and `Meteor.subscribe("customers");` respectively. Here is the html code for insert

```html
<template name="NewCustomer">
 <div class="new-customer">
  {{>quickForm collection="Customers" id="insertCustomerForm" type="insert" class="new-customer-form"}}
 </div>
</template>
```

But when i bootup the server and add a new customer, it doesn't work. Can anyone help me out? Thank you

Comment: Everything looks right to me. Where is the code that you are using to display the customer once it is inserted?

Comment: I am using meteortoys to check whether the customer is added, and I used the mongodb cli to check whether its added to the collection.

Comment: It looks right to me too. You don't have any error message?

Comment: none. I have no error messages whatsoever. I even deployed it on meteor, its still not saving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it out. This field in the collection

```js
nextSaleDate: {
  type: Date,
  label: "Next Sale Date",
  autoValue: function () {
   var thisDate = new Date();
   var dd = thisDate.getDate();
   var mm = thisDate.getMonth() + 3;
   var y = thisDate.getFullYear();

   var nextDate = dd + '/'+ mm + '/'+ y;
   return nextDate;
  },
  autoform: {
  type: "hidden"
  }
 },
```

is the one causing the issue. Thank you all for your input